# Drupal 7 form api radio box/checkbox image select

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, drupal, radio-button

I'm trying to make a  radio box display an image next to it  when selected with drupal 7 form api,and I've no idea where to start. I'd appreciate some help.Thank you

This is  the code I'm using:

```
 <?php


function test_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['test_module/form'] = array(
  'title' => t('Test'),
  'page callback' => 'test_module_form',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'description' => t('Test'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
   return $items;
}


function test_module_form() {
return drupal_get_form('test_module_my_form');

}
function test_module_my_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['house'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('None'), t('Choose a house'))),
  '#title' => t('Choose a house'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('house', 'None'),
  '#required' => 'TRUE',
);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out...

```
$images = array(
1 => 'theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'stylename', 'path' =>'/path/to/file.jpg', 'alt' => 'image alt', 'title' => 'image title',)),
2 => 'theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'stylename', 'path' => '/path/to/file2.jpg', 'alt' => 'image alt', 'title' => 'image title',)),
);
```

In may case I was using imagecache presets for the image.  Set up your array similar to above, or using theme('image', ...)

then something like...

```
$form['house'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => $images,
  '#title' => t('Choose a house'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('house', 'None'),
  '#required' => 'TRUE',
);
```

In my case I created the $images array dynamically and used the fid as key